# ms-access two-criteria query to update table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm sure this is a fairly easy and basic operation, but I'm learning ms-access by youtube and have no clue where to start researching this. Ultimately I want to take two fields from my main table, use those fields to pull the primary key from a second table and return that value to a third field in my main table.

Specifically:

I have a table with two fields, each field can have 5 values (1,2,3,4,5) and (A,B,C,D,E) . I have another table with a unique key for each permutation of number and letter: {[1,A,1]; [ 2,A,2]; [3,A,3]... [24,E,4]; [25,E,5]}.

So far I've been able to take the input from a form and run a query to spit out the key, so entering B and 5 returns 16, but this only returns the active field in the form, which is fine if I could record that result in the main table. For learning purposes I'd also like to be able to run a query and get the same result for every record I have.

Comment: Sometimes you can't just use videos.  Read documents on SQL syntax such as JOIN.  Include your query attempt in your post if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the best way to learn with Access is by using the various wizards and design tools.

In your case, you should click on the Create tab, and then choose Query Design.  When you do this, a pop-up appears Show Table.  Double click on both your main table and the table containing your keys, and then click close.  You will now see the two tables laid out side by side in a new Query tab (by default Query1).  Click on the integer field in your main table (the one that contains 1..5), and with the mouse click still down, drag to the equivalent value in your key table.  If you are successful, Access will show a line between the two fields.  Repeat for your character field (A..E) to produce a second line.

Now double click the fields you want to show in your result set.  They will appear in the bottom section.  In general you will want to select all the values from your main table and just the key field in your key table (the one that holds 1..25).

You can now select Run (!) (second from the left on the Toolbar) to execute the Query.

Having done this, I encourage you to click on the dropdown part of the first toolbar, where it says View (below the Set square image).  Doing this will give you the option to select SQL View.  If you do this, the main Query1 window will switch to showing you the underlying SQL that the designer has created for you.  At first this will be very strange to you, but with time, you will find that as you get better and your queries get more complex, you are often faster typing queries directly in SQL View rather than using the Wizards/Designer.  For now just notice the basic syntax.  This will be something like:

```
SELECT Maintable.Field1, Maintable.Field2, ... KeyTable.ID 
FROM MainTable INNER JOIN KeyTable
ON (Maintable.IDInt = KeyTable.IDInt) AND
(Maintable.IDChar = KeyTable.IDChar)
```

Your field names will be different, but the main syntax will be the same: SELECT x,y,z, ... FROM TableA inner join TableB ON TableA.p = TableB.q ...

This is the basic building block of all queries on a relational database, showing you how to link ("JOIN") related tables together by combining them "ON" the fields they have in common.

As you get more into it, your queries may link more than 2 tables together, but this will give you a start.